# Remove Default HTML response for status codes 403, 404, 500 in Restful services depoyed in JBoss EAP 6.2 Resteasy

Tags: jboss7.x, resteasy, jboss-eap-6

I have a Restful service running in Jboss EAP 6.2 + RestEasy 2.3.7 and I am returning 501, 404 error codes using below snippet in my code :

For 404,
throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
For 500,
throw new WebApplicationException();

When I am testing my service for these changes it sends back correct status code but the body has html information like the one shown below for 404.

[image: Error Snapshot - 404]
Please guide me on how to send blank response for these status codes.

Note:

I have tried below code too, bit it is not working.

```
        ResponseBuilder respBldr = Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN);
        respBldr.type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        respBldr.entity("");
        throw new WebApplicationException(respBldr.build());
```

Comment: One more thing: Your screenshot shows a 404, the FORBIDDEN status is 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in EAP 6.2.4.
Attaching the link (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1419).

Answer (score 1):

The error pages are generated in the `ErrorReportValve`. You can utilize the built-in `ExceptionMapper`s in order to produce your own response content (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html for docs). You can use `WebApplicationException` but you're not limited to these. An example for `IllegalArgumentException` could look like:

```
@Provider
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException exception) {        
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

It's up to you what you want to provide also in what representation. I posted some code from my recent projects which also contains an example for `WebApplicationException`: https://gist.github.com/mp911de/96991d30dbaa2604830e

I mostly used a status representation containing the code and sometimes useful contextual details.

Comment: Unfortunately github link doesn't work. Even after adding custom exception mapper, I am still getting the response body.